# Model Class with Catel ModelBase gets converted to an ExpandoObject(or kind of)

Tags: c#, json, catel

I'm trying to use Catel's ModelBase in my entities. Everything goes fine except that my WebApi returns the wrong result.

For example this should come out:

```
[{"VAT_Code_Id":"509d8ac2-8dc5-424d-9c3d-00c437ae4342","Description":"BTW Inkoop 21 %","Percentage":21.00,"General_Ledger_Account_Id":"90ed3df4-ea71-4562-97af-2d7c88a43a28","IsSales":false,"IsShifted":false,"IsExempt":false,"IsActive":true,"Tenant_Id":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","InputFirst":"24-6-2016 15:01:45 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","IsDeleted":false},{"VAT_Code_Id":"aa61f855-a41e-495b-84e8-3af4dcda8b80","Description":"BTW Verkoop 6 %","Percentage":6.00,"General_Ledger_Account_Id":"19eb883b-106f-4fe1-9144-88320cdc2c1a","IsSales":true,"IsShifted":false,"IsExempt":false,"IsActive":true,"Tenant_Id":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","InputFirst":"24-6-2016 15:01:45 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","IsDeleted":false},{"VAT_Code_Id":"803b6edf-8e55-43d6-b252-51d428c3af05","Description":"BTW Inkoop 6 %","Percentage":6.00,"General_Ledger_Account_Id":"cd6b3d53-bb53-4a2b-8fc8-1be154cabdba","IsSales":false,"IsShifted":false,"IsExempt":false,"IsActive":true,"Tenant_Id":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","InputFirst":"24-6-2016 15:01:45 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","IsDeleted":false},{"VAT_Code_Id":"93f6ac47-57e1-4622-bd41-d9f5fbf8a9cd","Description":"BTW Verkoop 21%","Percentage":21.00,"General_Ledger_Account_Id":"ac1437d5-343c-4c50-b865-89e89ffb0358","IsSales":true,"IsShifted":false,"IsExempt":false,"IsActive":true,"Tenant_Id":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","InputFirst":"24-6-2016 15:01:45 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","IsDeleted":false}]
```

But this is coming out of the converted class:

```
[{"PropertyValues":[{"Name":"Tenant_Id","Value":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Memo","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputFirst","Value":"24-6-2016 15:01:38 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputLast","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"IsDeleted","Value":false,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Compaction_Id","Value":"710162e7-e6cf-4df5-8426-01bc77096851","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Number","Value":49,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Description","Value":"Verschillen","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Account_Type","Value":4,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0}],"GraphId":1},{"PropertyValues":[{"Name":"Tenant_Id","Value":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Memo","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputFirst","Value":"24-6-2016 15:01:38 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputLast","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"IsDeleted","Value":false,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Compaction_Id","Value":"dd296092-6caf-438d-afab-01d9620d96c9","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Number","Value":80,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Description","Value":"Omzet","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Account_Type","Value":3,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0}],"GraphId":1},{"PropertyValues":[{"Name":"Tenant_Id","Value":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Memo","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputFirst","Value":"24-6-2016 15:01:38 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputLast","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"IsDeleted","Value":false,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Compaction_Id","Value":"53c626c6-742c-4b0b-9ba9-079f525fcfdc","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Number","Value":44,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Description","Value":"Kantoor en administratiekosten","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Account_Type","Value":4,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0}],"GraphId":1},{"PropertyValues":[{"Name":"Tenant_Id","Value":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Memo","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputFirst","Value":"24-6-2016 15:01:38 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputLast","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"IsDeleted","Value":false,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Compaction_Id","Value":"32d00a8e-6619-4729-9c8b-3539573ef187","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Number","Value":16,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Description","Value":"Belastingen te betalen","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Account_Type","Value":2,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0}],"GraphId":1},{"PropertyValues":[{"Name":"Tenant_Id","Value":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Memo","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputFirst","Value":"24-6-2016 15:01:38 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputLast","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"IsDeleted","Value":false,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Compaction_Id","Value":"43da90b3-131d-49bd-80c0-5a367cbdf055","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Number","Value":13,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Description","Value":"Belastingen te ontvangen","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Account_Type","Value":0,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0}],"GraphId":1},{"PropertyValues":[{"Name":"Tenant_Id","Value":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Memo","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputFirst","Value":"24-6-2016 15:01:38 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputLast","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"IsDeleted","Value":false,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Compaction_Id","Value":"d2ac699c-f52f-4c70-92e3-5fa8b581db01","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Number","Value":11,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Description","Value":"Liquide middelen","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Account_Type","Value":0,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0}],"GraphId":1},{"PropertyValues":[{"Name":"Tenant_Id","Value":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Memo","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputFirst","Value":"24-6-2016 15:01:38 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputLast","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"IsDeleted","Value":false,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Compaction_Id","Value":"6091a901-9b44-4730-9335-6698935ac2ec","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Number","Value":1,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Description","Value":"Inventaris","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Account_Type","Value":0,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0}],"GraphId":1},{"PropertyValues":[{"Name":"Tenant_Id","Value":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Memo","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputFirst","Value":"24-6-2016 15:01:38 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputLast","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"IsDeleted","Value":false,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Compaction_Id","Value":"fa00b1f9-e1b7-4425-a0f7-66c5d23073fe","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Number","Value":95,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Description","Value":"Buitengewone baten","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Account_Type","Value":3,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0}],"GraphId":1},{"PropertyValues":[{"Name":"Tenant_Id","Value":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Memo","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputFirst","Value":"24-6-2016 15:01:38 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputLast","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"IsDeleted","Value":false,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Compaction_Id","Value":"df04085e-1580-4398-8c57-71e7d433cf0d","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Number","Value":20,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Description","Value":"Tussenrekeningen","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Account_Type","Value":0,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0}],"GraphId":1},{"PropertyValues":[{"Name":"Tenant_Id","Value":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Memo","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputFirst","Value":"24-6-2016 15:01:38 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputLast","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"IsDeleted","Value":false,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Compaction_Id","Value":"5f34a5dc-e8a0-48d5-92d8-74e498c2141e","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Number","Value":0,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Description","Value":"Kapitaal","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Account_Type","Value":1,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0}],"GraphId":1},{"PropertyValues":[{"Name":"Tenant_Id","Value":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Memo","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputFirst","Value":"24-6-2016 15:01:38 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputLast","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"IsDeleted","Value":false,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Compaction_Id","Value":"6fdf8d78-f47b-4694-a324-7eb5363a406d","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Number","Value":90,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Description","Value":"Rentebaten","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Account_Type","Value":3,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0}],"GraphId":1},{"PropertyValues":[{"Name":"Tenant_Id","Value":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Memo","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputFirst","Value":"24-6-2016 15:01:38 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputLast","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"IsDeleted","Value":false,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Compaction_Id","Value":"68f65c23-2da0-413e-8d77-90b0d62d9a99","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Number","Value":18,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Description","Value":"Overige vorderingen / Overlopende activa","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Account_Type","Value":2,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0}],"GraphId":1},{"PropertyValues":[{"Name":"Tenant_Id","Value":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Memo","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputFirst","Value":"24-6-2016 15:01:38 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputLast","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"IsDeleted","Value":false,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Compaction_Id","Value":"2b040176-1a33-4070-911b-9d50d8db569c","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Number","Value":41,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Description","Value":"Belastingen","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Account_Type","Value":4,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0}],"GraphId":1},{"PropertyValues":[{"Name":"Tenant_Id","Value":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Memo","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputFirst","Value":"24-6-2016 15:01:38 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputLast","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"IsDeleted","Value":false,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Compaction_Id","Value":"9c60eec3-f7ec-4648-9cab-a25bc5476de7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Number","Value":15,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Description","Value":"Crediteuren","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Account_Type","Value":2,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0}],"GraphId":1},{"PropertyValues":[{"Name":"Tenant_Id","Value":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Memo","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputFirst","Value":"24-6-2016 15:01:38 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputLast","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"IsDeleted","Value":false,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Compaction_Id","Value":"afc2c680-da42-47f4-8c81-a935629ad2b7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Number","Value":43,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Description","Value":"Verkoopkosten","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Account_Type","Value":4,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0}],"GraphId":1},{"PropertyValues":[{"Name":"Tenant_Id","Value":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Memo","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputFirst","Value":"24-6-2016 15:01:38 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputLast","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"IsDeleted","Value":false,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Compaction_Id","Value":"0af18d3c-abe7-4472-9bc6-adc17e1038f8","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Number","Value":48,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Description","Value":"Algemene kosten","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Account_Type","Value":4,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0}],"GraphId":1},{"PropertyValues":[{"Name":"Tenant_Id","Value":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Memo","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputFirst","Value":"24-6-2016 15:01:38 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputLast","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"IsDeleted","Value":false,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Compaction_Id","Value":"b13710a3-b628-49b5-a6b6-ae84bfa35f0b","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Number","Value":85,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Description","Value":"Overige bedrijfsopbrengsten","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Account_Type","Value":3,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0}],"GraphId":1},{"PropertyValues":[{"Name":"Tenant_Id","Value":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Memo","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputFirst","Value":"24-6-2016 15:01:38 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputLast","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"IsDeleted","Value":false,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Compaction_Id","Value":"afc3f8a5-3faa-4d54-8cff-cff618da9ea0","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Number","Value":45,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Description","Value":"Autokosten","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Account_Type","Value":4,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0}],"GraphId":1},{"PropertyValues":[{"Name":"Tenant_Id","Value":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Memo","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputFirst","Value":"24-6-2016 15:01:38 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputLast","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"IsDeleted","Value":false,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Compaction_Id","Value":"d5a11e3e-4aba-4e0a-b278-dc2c19b8dedd","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Number","Value":30,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Description","Value":"Voorraden","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Account_Type","Value":0,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0}],"GraphId":1},{"PropertyValues":[{"Name":"Tenant_Id","Value":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Memo","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputFirst","Value":"24-6-2016 15:01:38 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputLast","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"IsDeleted","Value":false,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Compaction_Id","Value":"9619435a-fe3d-4cd6-b7c3-e54fa6ae2830","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Number","Value":40,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Description","Value":"Afschrijvingen","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Account_Type","Value":4,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0}],"GraphId":1},{"PropertyValues":[{"Name":"Tenant_Id","Value":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Memo","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputFirst","Value":"24-6-2016 15:01:38 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputLast","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"IsDeleted","Value":false,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Compaction_Id","Value":"c8dbaeea-3dc6-4dab-a6a4-ef6107ad42ad","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Number","Value":12,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Description","Value":"Debiteuren","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Account_Type","Value":0,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0}],"GraphId":1},{"PropertyValues":[{"Name":"Tenant_Id","Value":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Memo","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputFirst","Value":"24-6-2016 15:01:38 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputLast","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"IsDeleted","Value":false,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Compaction_Id","Value":"2126e52a-2395-4d7d-a1f2-f0fbe50fd351","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Number","Value":42,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Description","Value":"Huisvestingskosten","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Account_Type","Value":4,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0}],"GraphId":1},{"PropertyValues":[{"Name":"Tenant_Id","Value":"8e19405c-9e96-e511-bb01-6036dddba3f7","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Memo","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputFirst","Value":"24-6-2016 15:01:38 +00:00 - admin@demo.com","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"InputLast","Value":null,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"IsDeleted","Value":false,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Compaction_Id","Value":"860f1c38-c556-4e94-a346-f1d4594f0c68","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Number","Value":70,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Description","Value":"Inkoopwaarde","GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0},{"Name":"Account_Type","Value":4,"GraphId":0,"GraphRefId":0}],"GraphId":1}]
```

Is this a serialization issue?
This data I see at transportlevel with fiddler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long night I've kind of solved it by decorating the class with

> [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]

and the properties with

> [JsonProperty]

. It works but i'm starting to guess if this is the right way.